# GCM not sending or receiving - Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I have uploaded an .apk to the Play Store and have come across the following problem; The GCM is not sending or receiving notifications.

When I run the app from Android Studio, the GCM works fine. It sends and receives notifications. However when I download the release version of my app to my phone, the GCM does not work.

I have linked the sender ID in the Play Store, I have added both the release and debug SHA-1 finger prints in the console. I am unsure where else to look. The only thing I can think of is that I had to change the name of my package when I uploaded to Google Play Store and I am thinking that caused the problem because the release version of the app used to have a functioning GCM, now it doesn't.

I have updated the package name everywhere that I can think of. How do I get GCM to work again for the release version of my app?

Comment: Did you use proguard to optimize your apk?

Comment: @ezaquarii only to supress warnings

Comment: Try creating release build with old package version and test it. If it works, it's a package problem.

Comment: @ezaquarii I created new apk with old package version but the problem persists.

Comment: Try disabling proguard completely in release build.

Comment: @ezaquarii this solved my problem. But what if I dont want to disable progaurd? How do I filter out the problem rather than totally disabling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During our conversation we identified the problem - `Proguard` is probably obfuscating your code. Since Android does some reflection here and there, things may break.

You need to properly configure `Proguard` by adding appropriate exceptions, so it does not touch fragile fragments. For example, code that uses reflection will break if `Proguard` changes function of variable name.

Check this out - it says how to configure `Progurad` so it does not break `Play Services`:

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Remember: you WILL hit this problem over and over again in the future. A lot of libraries require `Proguard` exceptions.

Comment: Thanks. You have saved me a lot of time.